# Why would an indexed column return results slowly when querying for `IS NULL`?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, null, query-optimization

I have a table with 25 million rows, indexed appropriately.

But adding the clause `AND status IS NULL` turns a super fast query into a crazy slow query.

Please help me speed it up.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    student_id,
    grade,
    status
FROM 
    grades
WHERE 
        class_id = 1
    AND status IS NULL       -- This line delays results from <200ms to 40-70s!
    AND grade BETWEEN 0 AND 0.7
LIMIT 25;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grades` (
  `student_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade` FLOAT(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`student_id`,`class_id`),
  KEY `class_id` (`class_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `grade` (`grade`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Local development shows results instantly (<200ms). Production server is huge slowdown (40-70 seconds!).

Can you point me in the right direction to debug?

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type        | possible_keys         | key             | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | grades | index_merge | class_id,status,grade | status,class_id | 5,4     | NULL | 26811 | Using intersect(status,class_id); Using where          |
+----+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What does `explain select ...` output?

Comment: @juergend Added explain above.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: And change FLOAT to DECIMAL

Comment: @Strawberry Adding `ORDER BY` solved it. Thanks. Add as answer please.

Comment: The fact that `ORDER BY` sped the query back up, while a good suggestion in itself, is not an answer to the question.. don't rely on it to speed up similar queries in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement can only use one index per table.

Presumably the query before just did a scan using the sole index `class_id` for your condition `class_id=1`. Which will probably filter your result set nicely before checking the other conditions.

The optimiser is 'incorrectly' choosing an index merge on `class_id` and `status` for the second query and checking 26811 rows which is probably not optimal. You could hint at the `class_id` index by adding `USING INDEX (class_id)` to the end of the `FROM` clause.
You may get some joy with a composite index on `(class_id,status,grade)` which may run the query faster as it can match the first two and then range scan the `grade`. I'm not sure how this works with `null` though.

I'm guessing the `ORDER BY` pushed the optimiser to choose the `class_id` index again and returned your query to it's original speed.